# EKS Vertical Scaling With Karpenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, autoscaling, karpenter

I'm evaluating Karpenter (https://karpenter.sh/) and I wanted to know if there's a way to vertically scale down a large node with few pods. The only scaling actions seem to be triggered by either unschedulable pods or empty nodes.

Scenario: I scheduled **5** pods and the scheduler gave me one `c5d.2xlarge` instance, and that resulted in a **65%** utilization (not bad). I killed **3** pods and utilization dropped as expected to **25%**. I waited for a few hours to see if an optimization process would kick in but .. nothing (over **20** hours). The feature is not well documented, in fact the only reference of it is in this independent article: https://blog.sivamuthukumar.com/karpenter-scaling-nodes-seamlessly-in-aws-eks

> How does it work?
>
> 1. Observes the pod resource requests of unscheduled pods
> 2. Direct provision of Just-in-time capacity of the node. (Groupless Node
>    Autoscaling)
> 3. Terminating nodes if outdated
> 4. Reallocating the pods in nodes for better resource utilization

Am I missing something? Is there a way to do this, using Karpenter or another solution? TIA

Answer (score 1):

So there's a feature request on Karpenter's Github project addressing this specific issue: https://github.com/aws/karpenter/issues/1091. I'll update this answer once a solution is available.

The workaround suggested by the project team, was to set a short TTL on the nodes (like **1 day**), forcing Karpenter to evaluate optimization daily.